# Method skipping to execute some code

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Code

```
 private void updateQuestion() {
    mDatabaseReference.child("Users").child(RecieversId).child("Quiz").child("Question" + mQuestionNumber).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String question = dataSnapshot.child("Question").getValue().toString();
            answer = dataSnapshot.child("Answer").getValue().toString();
            option1 = dataSnapshot.child("Option1").getValue().toString();
            option2 = dataSnapshot.child("Option2").getValue().toString();
            option3 = dataSnapshot.child("Option3").getValue().toString();
            option4 = dataSnapshot.child("Option4").getValue().toString();
            que.setText(question);
            opt1.setText(option1);
            opt2.setText(option2);
            opt3.setText(option3);
            opt4.setText(option4);
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });

    opt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (option1.equals(answer)) {
                opt1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                mScore++;
                sco.setText("Score : " + mScore);
                final Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mQuestionNumber++;
                        qn.setText("Question : " + mQuestionNumber);
                        updateQuestion();
                        opt1.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
                    }
                }, 1500);
            } else
                opt1.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            sco.setText("Score : " + mScore);
            final Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mQuestionNumber++;
                    qn.setText("Question : " + mQuestionNumber);
                    updateQuestion();
                    opt1.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
                }
            }, 1500);
        }
    });
    opt2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (option2.equals(answer)) {
                opt2.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                mScore++;
                sco.setText("Score : " + mScore);
                final Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mQuestionNumber++;
                        qn.setText("Question : " + mQuestionNumber);
                        updateQuestion();
                        opt2.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
                    }
                }, 1500);
            } else
                opt2.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            sco.setText("Score : " + mScore);
            final Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mQuestionNumber++;
                    qn.setText("Question : " + mQuestionNumber);
                    updateQuestion();
                    opt2.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
                }
            }, 1500);
        }
    });
    opt3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (option3.equals(answer)) {
                opt3.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                mScore++;
                sco.setText("Score : " + mScore);
                final Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mQuestionNumber++;
                        qn.setText("Question : " + mQuestionNumber);
                        updateQuestion();
                        opt3.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
                    }
                }, 1500);
            } else
                opt3.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            sco.setText("Score : " + mScore);
            final Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mQuestionNumber++;
                    qn.setText("Question : " + mQuestionNumber);
                    updateQuestion();
                    opt3.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
                }
            }, 1500);
        }
    });
    opt4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (option4.equals(answer)) {
                opt4.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                mScore++;
                sco.setText("Score : " + mScore);
                final Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mQuestionNumber++;
                        qn.setText("Question : " + mQuestionNumber);
                        updateQuestion();
                        opt4.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
                    }
                }, 1500);
            } else
                opt4.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            sco.setText("Score : " + mScore);
            final Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mQuestionNumber++;
                    qn.setText("Question : " + mQuestionNumber);
                    updateQuestion();
                    opt4.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
                }
            }, 1500);
        }
    });
    }
}
```

It's behaving quite weird. When I get the first question and I select a wrong answer it goes to the next question without any problem. But when I select a correct answer it skips the next question and goes to the question after that. For example if I select a correct answer in question 2 it skips question 3 and shows question 4. It's quite weird and I'm not able to figure out where I have gone wrong.

I'm sure some mistake in my if statement but not able to figure out what it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your both handlers, you are calling

```
 mQuestionNumber++;
 updateQuestion();
```

calling two times if answer is correct

```
if(correct){
   handler //once
}else{
}
handler //twice
```

Solution is to remove `first //once` handler

i.e.

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mQuestionNumber++;
                        qn.setText("Question : " + mQuestionNumber);
                        updateQuestion();
                        opt1.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
                    }
                }, 1500);
```

remove this from `if condition`

update for `opt1`

```
opt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (option1.equals(answer)) {
                opt1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                mScore++;
            } else
                opt1.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            sco.setText("Score : " + mScore);
            final Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mQuestionNumber++;
                    qn.setText("Question : " + mQuestionNumber);
                    updateQuestion();
                    opt1.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
                }
            }, 1500);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Remove "handler" from every if condition

Comment: where should the if come then? i mean without if how to identify if the answer is right or weong

Comment: Just remove handler that's it. keep if condition like that only

Comment: can i get the code for 1 button? because your answer is exactly the same as my code